# How do i open DJI SDK system logs?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to read the DJI SDK logs from my app.

I tried opening the files but they seem to be encoded.

I tried for example to read from android device folder Android/.../SDKLog/Logs.

Do i need a special app or service to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to report but the formatting and encoding of the log files is proprietary and not public.  There have been a few efforts to reverse-engineer the logs but they are incomplete and not official so I cannot suggest them.

There is no SDK access to parse the logs, not that I have ever found.

I (personally) and other 3rd party apps pretty much create our own logging specific to the application's needs.